# Setting a Boolean as a field of an object from another script

Tags: unity, c#

I saw this question asked some times but no one correlates to mine. I see people using the GetComponent() function but this one should work too.

First I receive a Bool value from a toggle button and assign it as a field of the object 'hydro':

```
hydroControl.cs

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;

public class hydroProwerControlPanel : MonoBehaviour {
private HydroElectric hydro;
public bool t1;

void Start () 
{ 
    t1 = true;
}

public hydroProwerControlPanel (){
    hydro = new HydroElectric();
}
public void turbine1State (bool t1) {
     hydro.t1Bool = t1;
}
```

Then I have the object where this bool change should be recognized and sent as an output, but it doesn't:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
namespace Assets.Code.PowerPlants
{
    public class HydroElectric
    {
        public bool t1Bool;
        float turbina1;

        public float prod;

        public HydroElectric ()
        {   
          t1Bool = true;
          prod = 0f; 
        }

        public float ControlPanel ()
        {
            turbina1 = t1Bool ? 1.5F : 0;   

            prod = turbina1 ;
            Debug.Log (prod);
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, this is where the function ControlPanel() is called:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;
namespace Assets.Code.Interfaces
{

public class PlayLevel1 : MonoBehaviour 
{
private HydroElectric hydro;
public Text producao;

public PlayLevel1 ()
{
    hydro = new HydroElectric();
}

public void OnGUI()
{
 producao.text = hydro.ControlPanel().ToString();          
}
}
}
```

Do you have any idea why does this Bool does not get updated? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, your asking for an explanation of the particular reason, not a means to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually referring to 2 different instances of `HydroElectric`, which is why you're not seeing the `bool` change value.

As it stands `hydroProwerControlPanel` holds an instance of `HydroElectric` whose value changes when you call `turbineState`, but `PlayLevel1` holds a completely different instance of `HydroElectric` and that instances value is never modified.

There are a couple of ways around this. You could implement the **Singleton** pattern if there is only ever going to be one `HydroElectric` per scene, or you can pass `PlayLevel1` the instance of `HydroElectric` that you want to monitor (known as **Dependency Injection**)

More details on Singletons in Unity can be found here:
https://rockonflash.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/singletons-in-unity3d/ 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

More details on Dependency Injection in Unity can be found here:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Dependency_injection 
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/07/dependency-injection-and-abstractions/